# In Android, sharing an audio file to SoundCloud no longer works

Tags: android, soundcloud

Previously, if I choose an mp3 file (with audio/mpeg MIME type) and share it, there is a choice to upload to SoundCloud.

Now, the only choice is "Record" from SoundCloud, which does not seem to read the mp3 file at all, instead asking the user to record a new file.

I have tried both the standard "android.intent.action.SEND" action and
the SoundCloud-specific "com.soundcloud.android.SHARE" action. Both sends me to the Record interface.

Testing intent from the `adb shell`:

```
 am start -a com.soundcloud.android.SHARE --es android.intent.extra.STREAM file:///storage/emulated/0/Recordings/recording-20150622-101838.mp3
```

Why is this so, and is it true that we can no longer upload an audio file from another app to SoundCloud?

Comment: Mentioned in user comments as well: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.soundcloud.android&reviewId=Z3A6QU9xcFRPR1diY0ZPc2FZS2hEQXQtMnpTN2Z6SWVwV2ctTVAyQlJwUjU1LUlwLU9yYk1nYWYxWDFOalJTQmo5QTJaVmw1Q2dfOF94Vl9yTF92dkpvUmc

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior. Actually, there's no way to share an audio file on Android using the soundcloud app with the latest version. For me this looks like a major bug. I don't think that they just turned sharing off, since there's no sign of such a task on their developer blog. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101260/soundcloud-android-explicit-intent-sharing-does-not-work-anymore

Answer (score 1):

I've reported this problem to the SoundCloud support. It actually is a bug. I also got a beta build of the next SoundCloud update, which obviously contains a bug fix ... with the beta it works again. So I'm pretty sure it'll be fixed in the next SoundCloud release.

Answer (score 0):

to confirm Gals answer: Spoke to SC and they said: "I can confirm that this is a known issue in our Android app. It will be fixed in our next Android release, which is currently scheduled to ship in about a week (mid-July). "