# SoundCloud Android explicit Intent sharing does not work anymore

Tags: android, android-intent, soundcloud, sharing, explicit

Since the latest SoundCloud App update on Android, the explicit intent sharing (from other app) does not work anymore. Instead of showing the share page (which is normally called by the intent), it starts to record audio over the microphone, which is definitely wrong.

I checked developers.soundcloud.com, there's neither a sign that explicit intent sharing is no longer support, nor anything else in that direction. So it looks more like a major bug in the latest SoundCloud update on Android.

Does anyone experience the same behavior?
And is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I got an answer from the SoundCloud Support. It actually appears to be a bug. I also got a beta build of the next SoundCloud update, which obviously contains a bug fix ... with the beta it works again. So I'm pretty sure it'll be fixed in the next release.